# Add to nav custom type posts WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a menu consisting of posts custom type, but they are not present in the selection menu.
Can be I forgot what the properties on custom type?

My code:

```
//Создание страницы новостроек

add_action( 'init', 'register_house_page' ); // Использовать функцию только внутри хука init

function register_house_page() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Новостройки КРЕО',
        'singular_name' => 'Новостройки', // админ панель Добавить->Функцию
        'add_new' => 'Добавить новостройку',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую новостройку', // заголовок тега <title>
        'edit_item' => 'Редактировать новостройку',
        'new_item' => 'Новая новостройка',
        'all_items' => 'Все новостройки',
        'view_item' => 'Просмотр новостройки на сайте',
        'search_items' => 'Искать новостройку',
        'not_found' =>  'Новостроек не найдено.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине нет новостроек.',
        'menu_name' => 'Новостройки КРЕО' // ссылка в меню в админке
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, // показывать интерфейс в админке
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite', // иконка в меню
        'menu_position' => 21, // порядок в меню
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies'          => array(),
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true, // зависит от public
    );
    register_post_type('kreo_house', $args);
}
```

I have 4 posts
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjTYS.png)

but cant see in menu

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR8ot.png)

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37787/adding-a-custom-post-type-into-the-menu-screen It solved my problem. It was simple.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if when you say that you want to create a menu related with the custom post types are you talking into the dashboard or directly in you page but based in you code, I'm assuming that you are trying to show your custom post type in the dashboard for that you could use something similar to this

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_new_post' );
function create_post_type_new_post() {
    register_post_type( 'new-post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Новостройки КРЕО' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Новостройки КРЕО' )
                //more options here
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'new-post'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
            'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
            //more options here
        )
    );
}
```

I added normally the code mentioned above in a separate file and imported it into the functions.php file

```
   $file = TEMPLATEPATH."/inc/your-name-file.php";
   if(file_exists($file)){
     require_once($file);
   }
```

I hope this could help you!

**UPDATE:**
If you want to show your custom post type in the menu or your site, you need to create a custom link in the menu section, linked to the archive

If archives are enabled for a custom post type, then you can display them on your website.The URL of your custom post type archive page should be like this:

http://yoursite.com/post-type-slug/

You can place a link for the archives for each custom post type into your navigation menus.

You need to visit Appearance > Menus page.
You need to click on the name of your custom post
You will see an option for your post type archives.

If after this you continue without see your menu option, try the follow:

Enable debug option adding to your wp-config.php and verify if some error is appearing

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Sometimes the custom post type name's lenght causes errors

Comment: Hello Jorge, welcome to StackOverflow :-) Your answer seems to be equivalent to the code that the question author already has. To make your answer valuable, please add an explanation of the difference to your code, that solves the question.

Comment: want to add pages to the menu on the site, not in the administrative panel.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to add it and how verify is some error is appearing in order to try the fix the issue